# How to specify the character set in the HTTP Content-Type response header?

Tags: optimization, character-encoding, http-headers, content-type

I had my site tested with the [Page Speed](https://developers.google.com/pagespeed) app from Google and one of the suggestions was to specify the character set in the HTTP Content-Type response header claiming it was better than just in a meta tag.

Here's what I understand I need to write:
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

..but where exactly should I put this? I'm on a shared server.

Thank you!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

*Apache*: add to your **.htaccess** file in root directory:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

It will modify the header from this:

**Content-Type  text/html**

...to this:

**Content-Type  text/html; charset=UTF-8**

---

*nginx* [[doc](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_charset_module.html#charset)] [[serverfault Q](https://serverfault.com/questions/312177/how-to-enable-correct-charset-http-header-in-nginx)]

```
server {
   # other server config...
   charset utf-8;
}
```

add `charset utf-8;` to *server* block (and reload nginx config)

Comment: I know it should simply work but my HTTP Header still just respond with Content-Type text/html. I don't want to use a <meta> tag in my document to declare the character encoding. I use Apache 2.4.

Comment: @Tomkay make sure the server process .htaccess directives and the file is located in the proper directory

Answer (score 3):

When i added this, my response header looked like this:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   **Content-Type: text/html,text/html;charset='UTF-8'**
>   Vary: Accept-Encoding
>   Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5

Comment: UTF-8 seems to be the default for IIS (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771836%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

With Apache, you use http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#adddefaultcharset

With IIS you edit the MIME type for the filetype in the list of files.

With most server-side technologies like PHP or ASP.NET there's a method or property provided by that technology. For example in ASP.NET you can set it in config, page, or page code-behind.