# WOFF2 - HTTP Content-Type response header suggestion

Tags: .htaccess, woff

I'm doing some website optimisations using [PageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/). I faced a next suggestion:

> The following resources have no character set specified in their HTTP
> headers. Specifying a character set in HTTP headers can speed up
> browser rendering.

```
http://localhost:8892/.../FocoBold.woff2
http://localhost:8892/.../FocoRegular.woff2
http://localhost:8892/.../GTblack.woff2
```

I've instantly started google and found a [relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963390/how-to-specify-the-character-set-in-the-http-content-type-response-header) on StackOverFlow.

I've added next line to `.htaccess` but it didn't worked for me.

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

Next thing I've tried, but still no results.

```
AddType font/woff2 .woff2
```

Can anyone help me with that?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I was having the same problem.

I think that [pagespeed](/questions/tagged/pagespeed) is misreporting the underlying cause which is not so much a lack of definition of the charset, but a lack of definition of the [content-type](/questions/tagged/content-type).  Without that's being defined, it / most browsers assume what is being sent back is text/html, where, indeed, no charset has been defined, especially as the [.woff2](/questions/tagged/.woff2) file will contain "non-standard" (ASCII!) chars.

My solution (it may not work if your [apache](/questions/tagged/apache) environment is significantly different, such as not allowing [addtype](/questions/tagged/addtype) in `.htaccess` files) was to add the following to the `.htaccess` in the relevant root of the site being served:

```
AddType application/x-font-woff2 .woff2
```

(Found this [resource](https://gist.github.com/sergejmueller/cf6b4f2133bcb3e2f64a))

Worked for me!

[.htaccess](/questions/tagged/.htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

In .htaccess AddType should be in mod_mime.c module

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
AddType application/woff2 .woff2
</IfModule>
```